# Class Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config does not exist in 2.4.4

Tags: logging

After upgrading from Magento 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4, I am getting the following error:

```
In ClassReader.php line 57:
  Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config $config ]
  of Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\Logger\NewRelic class

In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:
  Class Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config does not exist
```

And sure enough, when I look through vendor and generated code, I do not see any such class. Is this just "fresh release" problems with 2.4.4? Is there some way to disable NewRelic globally?

This is in a Docker dev environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your project `composer.json` file, and make sure `magento/module-new-relic-reporting` is not removed.

But I think Magento requires NewRelic classes on Graphql module by this way is the wrong way.